# How to change the cnosdb config with restart the cnosdb binary?

Tags: cnosdb

how to change the cnosdb config with restart the cnosdb binary? I want to change some cnosdb-cluster config, but i dont want to restart the cnosdb cluster , how can i do that with no shutdown time?